# Is 'Lets gather miles together' an acceptable sentence?

Tags: grammar, sentence, simile

- Lets gather miles together.

Is this a proper sentence?

Can we use the verb 'gather' for mileages?

Comment: Mileage as in how far a vehicle has traveled, or how much petrol it is using per mile, or something else? Do you mean you want to produce a document with details of mileage?

Comment: You can 'gather _air-miles_' as they're a type of points system. But this sentence sounds very unidiomatic.

Comment: It could be construed as poetic, a kind of metaphor, if your poem were asking the object of your affection to take a trip with you. But I agree that this is not a normal idiomatic usage.

Comment: It should be *let's* (with an apostrophe). That aside, what are you trying to express? Where the people should meet, or that they should travel a lot? In either case, the meaning is ambiguous in the standalone sentence.